# How to use REGEX to replace just commas outside quotes?

Tags: regex, csv

I have .CSV files that follow the example below

```
22645.30003,2013 Mar 31,4:00:00,5:59:59,"Twilight Saga, The: Breaking Dawn - Part 2","Condon, Bill",,,4
```

I need to replace the comma as column separator by the symbol \ leaving intact all the commas ocurring inside the strings enclosed in quotes and intend to use it in a simple FIND and REPLACE in Notepad++ for instance.

Comment: This is not a programming question and thus not intended for SO.

Comment: If the regex solution's don't work, you might want to try Excel: [How do I save an excel spreadsheet as a semi-colon separated values file?](http://superuser.com/q/476327)

Answer (score 4):

You can try this

```
search :  ,("[^"]*")?

replace : \\\1
```

(tested and works on version 6.3.2)

Comment: @Cyborgx37: Have you tested it on notepad++?

Comment: I don't have Notepad++ - but my initial comment was incorrect. If Notepad++ skips replaced text (not normal behavior), then this might actually work.

Comment: Once something is matched, it can not be matched a second time, its a normal behaviour

Comment: Note: this will only work in more recent versions of Notepad++. earlier versions do not support certain operators, including `or` and `?`

Comment: @Casimir - yep, you're right. I'm an idiot.

Comment: @Alan: right, seems not recognize anything in the old version 5.8.3

Answer (score 3):

Following regex

```
(,)(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)
```

matches all commas outside quotation.

[ReFiddle](http://refiddle.co/gpk)

Comment: Second time I see that link today, and it doesn't work this time either.

Comment: @melwil I just googled "regex online". It works for me.

Comment: Regexes are not all the same. Notepad++ uses POSIX. I don't believe that lookaheads, etc, are supported POSIX notation. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html.