# R Reading a badly formatted csv with uneven quotes and separators in fields

Tags: r, csv, import, data-import

I have a badly formatted csv file (I did not make it) that includes both separators and broken quotes in some fields. I would like to read this into R.

Three lines of the table look something like this:

```
| ids    |info           | text                                   |
| id 1   |extra_info;1998| text text text                         |
| id 2   |extra_info2    | text with broken dialogues quotes "hi! |

#the same table in R string could be
string <- "ids;info;text\n\"id 1\";\"extra_info;1998\";\"text text text\"\n\"id 2\";extra_info2;\"text with broken dialogues quotes \"hi!\" \n"
```

With " quotes surrounding any field with more than one word as is common in csv-s, and semicolon ; used as a separator. Unfortunately the way it was built, the last column (and it is always last), can contain a random number of semicolons or quotes within a text bulk, and these quotes are not always escaped.

I'm looking for a way to read this file. So far I have come up with a really complicated workflow to replace the first N separators with another less used separator when they are in the beginning of line with regex (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359785/how-to-use-regex-to-replace-just-commas-outside-quotes)) - because text is always last, however this still fails currently when there is an uneven number of quotes in the line.

I'm thinking there must be an easier way to do this, as badly formed csv-s should be a reoccurring problem here. Thanks.

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem with just getting the three columns into a data frame (I think).  Is your issue more about how to use the data after you have read it into R?  Honestly, your efforts might be better spent going back to your data source and cleaning it up there.

Comment: I am getting rather sad in the wasted effort indeed. Unfortunately this is the type of csv that a database gives out written by programmers 10 years moved on. This is basically just how they give metadata and text, unfortunately metadata includes separators and text includes both quotes and separators. I could provide an example file too. But so far I am struggling simply getting the right info to right columns.

Comment: Maybe show us how you want the table to look after the scrubbing is finished.

Comment: This is not going to be an easy task. And probably more difficult in R than other languages because it's not super great at reading files character-by-character. R pretty much assumes you have valid, rectangular data files to input. Malformed input files are not robustly supported.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The file had a few more issues, and with too much hacking I managed to create a workaround. fread does most of the tasks, but still can fail with too much text and newlines in a column, and possibly unbalanced quotes. As @MrFlick says, it's not an easy task to hack on this case-by-case, and for a future me, I would advise to avoid it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.table::fread` works wonders:

```
library(data.table)
test <- fread("test.csv")
# Remove extraneous columns
test$V1 <- NULL
test$V5 <- NULL
```

Comment: What version of `data.table` are you using? Current dev version reads `string` from OP without extraneous columns

Comment: also, FWIW `$<-` approach to deleting columns is incorrect for `data.table`; we've found that these functions can result in your whole table being copied incidentally. `test[ , V1 := NULL]` will be sure to remove the column without this copy

Comment: @MichaelChirico data.table 1.11.4, but I should mention I'm running R 3.4.3. I wasn't aware of the `$ <-` issue. Does it affect the assigned variable, or just chew up a whole lot of memory?

Comment: Thanks for your help, i've accepted your answer - fread indeed has no problems reading a small table with unbalanced quotes. It seems to have issues with bigger tables with lots of linebreaks and quotes, but maybe it will improme.